# How to fix "[WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it" on entering first loop in Selenium Python?

Tags: python, selenium

I wrote a simple hypothetical program that opens a browser, goes to x website, takes a screenshot, closes said browser and then does it again.

```
from selenium import webdriver
geckodriver = r'geckodriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=geckodriver)
print('Selenium webdriver setup complete')

for x in range(2):
    driver.get('https://www.google.com')
    driver.save_screenshot('data/WorkArea/image{}.png'.format(x))
    print('Took screenshot {}'.format(x))
    driver.quit()
```

While the code takes the first screenshot successfully, the code runs into an error at the start of the first loop. The termial output that includes the error message can be seen here:

```
Selenium webdriver setup complete
Took screenshot 0
Project1Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 160, in _new_conn
    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 80, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 70, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 603, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 355, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1244, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1290, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1239, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1026, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\http\client.py", line 966, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 183, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 169, in _new_conn
    self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x032F65F0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\CodingProjects\Project1\t.py", line 12, in <module>
    driver.get('https://www.google.com')
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 333, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 319, in execute
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 374, in execute
    return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 397, in _request
    resp = self._conn.request(method, url, body=body, headers=headers)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\request.py", line 72, in request
    **urlopen_kw)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\request.py", line 150, in request_encode_body
    return self.urlopen(method, url, **extra_kw)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\poolmanager.py", line 326, in urlopen
    response = conn.urlopen(method, u.request_uri, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 670, in urlopen
    **response_kw)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 670, in urlopen
    **response_kw)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 670, in urlopen
    **response_kw)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 641, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 399, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=(REDACTED)): Max retries exceeded with url: /session/(REDACTED)/url (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at REDACTED>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'))
```

Note that i redacted some things in the last line, as i'm unsure wether or not it's fragile information. Hope you can do without it.
I am quite new to programming in general myself, so i'd be really thankful if somebody could figure out whats going on here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling driver.quit() at the bottom of every loop. Either don't call it until the end by unindenting it, or reinitialize the driver object every time.

```
from selenium import webdriver
geckodriver = r'geckodriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=geckodriver)
print('Selenium webdriver setup complete')

for x in range(2):
    driver.get('https://www.google.com')
    driver.save_screenshot('data/WorkArea/image{}.png'.format(x))
    print('Took screenshot {}'.format(x))
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the close() function instead of quit().

driver.close() closes the browser.

driver.quit() closes the driver ie chromedriver, geckodriver